# USRP E310 Beginner

Tags: putty, usrp

I am new to the Ettus device.  We have a Ettus USRP E310 device, but we don't have the original mini SD Card (boot into Linux).

I tried to create the new mini SD Card 16 GB with the image download from http://files.ettus.com/e3xx_images/e3xx-release-4/ettus-e3xx-sg3/ website.

Everything successfully imaged and connected to it using the PuTTy but without IP Address.  I am no longer be able connect to the device configured the IP address for device.  There is no Linux command prompt from the PuTTy console.

Would anyone point me to location to download the image already configured with default IP address?  I contacted with Ettus technical support but not get much helps.

Thank you in advance for your time and your helps.

Answer (score 0):

The default IP address for new version of USRP E310 is set as 192.168.10.42. The older version of USRP E310 of the default IP address is set as 192.168.0.118

When in doubt use the Console Serial Connection, then use ifconfig to set the IP to then SSH into it to set a static IP etc.